# What is go.houseparty.com?

Tags: dns, internet, domain, privacy, subdomain

I have installed a Pi-Hole in my network and I was checking the querys from my devices. I discovered that the domain `go.houseparty.com` was repeatedly showing up.

I have not installed the houseparty app, and I haven't visited one of their websites.

Does anyone know whether this is some kind of tracker that Tencent implements on websites? I did some own research but couldn't find out about the purpose of this domain.

Comment: It's something facebook-like. Nothing dangerous about it.